# KDE Neon Spanish error: No se pudo entrar en la carpeta tags:/

Tags: kde, plasma

I have this error in Spanish and I don't know how it exactly will be written in English. My problem: I am in kde neon and when I turn on my computer I get this error:

```
  Error kde plasma
  No se pudo entrar en la carpeta tags:/
```

And I also get this error when I try to open a folder, can someone tell me why this error happens and how can I fix it?

Comment: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=154&t=171518  kf.kio.core: "Could not enter folder tags:/."

Answer (score 0):

You may have this problem:

[Could not enter folder tags:/](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=437176#c4)

Try to run the command

```
balooctl purge
```

(as the user who has the problem) and let us know.  Perhaps you need to log out and log back in for the change to take effect.

When you run the command you may see a message like "Deleted the index database".  That is normal.

Comment: Hi I tried what you said and got this message `Deleted the index database`, is that good or bad?

Comment: @DavidFloresGarcía That's no problem. It will be re-created when needed. Do you still get that error message?

Comment: Yes I still get the message

Comment: @DavidFloresGarcía Have you rebooted and still get the message? When exactly does it appear?

Comment: I get the message when i turn on my computer and when i try to open dolphin